# Nginx server blocks

Tags: nginx, virtual-ip-address

I'm trying to set my nginx to have 2 server blocks, one that lead to the default one atm and one that leads to my loadbalancer.

So I have set up my loadbalancer like this.

```
upstream backend {
  server 192.168.24.28;
  server 192.168.24.47;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name MYURL

location / {
  proxy_set_header HOST $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_pass http://backend;
  proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

and the default i have changed the listen to be

```
listen 192.168.24.30:80 default_server;
```

And the servers ip is `192.168.24.99`

So if I understand it correctly, my settings should put the loadbalancer at `192.168.24.99` and the default at `192.168.24.30`

So loadbalancer is placed correctly, but the `192.168.24.30` just gives me

```
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Try removing `proxy_set_header` field

Comment: Still getting same issue

Comment: Solved, had to add the ip's to the ens